# Python unsupported operand type on a list

Tags: python

I have the following 2d python list `mylist` of coordinates...

```
[[294.0, 351.0], [486.0, 255.5]]
```

I am trying to determine which one of these points is closest to the center of a 500x500 area like this...

```
def sqr_dist(a, b):
    # return square of distance between points a and b #
    return (a[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (a[1] - b[1]) ** 2

central = min( mylist, key=lambda r: sqr_dist( (mylist[0], mylist[1]), (500, 500) ) )
```

But I am getting error...

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

I assume this is telling me that I can't use `min` on a `list`

If this is the case then what is my alternative?

Comment: a=[1,2,3]
print(a/3)   output:TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqr_dist( (mylist[0], mylist[1]), (500, 500) )
b=(500, 500)
a[0]=[294.0, 351.0]
b[0]=500
```

`so you cannot subtract list with integer(a[0] - b[0])` 
 as your error shows - symbol  `-: 'list' and 'int'`

the correct way to do it

```
central = min( mylist, key=lambda r: sqr_dist( r, (500, 500) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of the a[0]-b[0]. a[0] is a list, b[0] is an integer.
So what you should do is:

```
mylist = [[294.0, 351.0], [486.0, 255.5]]

def sqr_dist(a, b):
    # return square of distance between points a and b #
    return (a[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (a[1] - b[1]) ** 2

central = min(mylist, key=lambda r: sqr_dist( r, (500.0, 500.0) ) )
```

The difference is that now I'm passing the `r` (a list) to the `sqr_dist` in the lambda. The problem is with the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You were just using lambda wrong.

Your error means that you are trying to do a `-`, subtraction, between a `list`, and an `int`. That is because you were passing both to your `sqr_dist` function. The correct way to do this is:

```
central = min( mylist, key=lambda r: sqr_dist( r, (500, 500) ) )
```